# Spring doResolveException in SimpleMappingExceptionResolver not getting called

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
package com.beebunny.springapp.exception.resolvers;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver;

public class MyExceptionResolver extends SimpleMappingExceptionResolver {

    private static final String ERROR_PAGE = "path/to/error/page.html";

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView doResolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler,
            Exception ex) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(ERROR_PAGE);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

I have a controller that I wrote to just throw an exception. I am expecting the class above to have its doResolveException get trigged. I need to do things in here such as logging, call an API, and some other custom handling.

Unfortunately, the version of Spring I'm working with doesn't support @ControllerAdvice, and so I'm falling back to SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.

My requirement is that I need an exception handler that will catch any uncaught exceptions if something blows up for any reason.

Not sure what the common reasons are for this to not work.

**I do have context:component-scan defined in my bean config with the base-package containing the package for my exception handler implementation above.**

Edit: Here is the relevant line from my bean config:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.beebunny.springapp"/>
```

Comment: Post your Spring config. Did you register it as a bean?

Comment: Well if you want to have the exception resolver picked-up by component scan, then it should be probably annotated as `@Component` ?

Comment: Just updated my original post above to show the relevant line from my Spring config.
@BohuslavBurghardt: I'll add the @ Component annotation and try again.

Comment: Tried adding the component annotation - no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is two-fold.

1. I needed to add the @Component annotation to my MyExceptionResolver class, which extends SimpleMappingExceptionResolver. +1 to Bohuslav Burghardt for pointing that out in his comment.
2. In my beanconfig, I was relying on context:component-scan to pick up my @Component annotated class and just work.

Instead, I had to add a property to MyExceptionResolver and explicitly specify this bean in my Spring config. So to MyExceptionResolver, I added this property.

```
private int order;
```

And then, as I said, I had to explicitly define this bean, and I had to manually specify a value for this order property, as so:

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="com.beebunny.springapp.exception.resolvers.MyExceptionResolver">
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

In other words, my project had a default exception resolver, and I just needed to override the order that the exception resolvers are used in.